# How to shorten first name in a .bib list?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I have a .bib file which is a mix (due to historical reason) of several styles of brevity (I am sure I am not the first to have this problem). One thing which I find quite annoying is that some entries have just the first letter of the first name and others have full first name.

Is there a way to shorten the first name, through the .tex bib command, so that the lowest common denominator is chosen among all these entries (i.e. always first letter of first name)?

I do wish there was a way to actually expand the first names appropriately, but that is of course somewhat of a SciFi...

Comment: If you are using `biblatex`, you just need to add the option `firstinits=true`.

Comment: @Corentin, I'd rather not use biblatex, if possible.

Comment: This is achieved using `format.names$` in the `.bst` file. However, you can't scan through and then decide whether to abbreviate: you have to decide that as part of creating the `.bst` file. Could you tell us which one you use so we can suggest an edit.

Answer (score 4):

The treatment of names is governed by your bibliography style. Some styles will automatically abbreviate all first names. Or modify the style you're using [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612569/automatically-abbreviate-authors-first-names-in-latex).

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the link @Tyler gave you, some styles abbreviate first names automatically by using `f.~` instead of `ff` in `format.names$`. So if your still free to chose your bibliography style, you can either chose one [here](http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/~kjt/software/latex/showbst.html), or check which of the style files use the aforementioned format. This script

```
styles=`find /usr/share/texmf -name "*.bst" -exec grep -H "f\.~" {} \; |cut -d: -f1| uniq`
for f in $styles; do
   echo `basename $f .bst`
done
```

gave me this list:
`osajnl
sweabbrv
pccp
revcompchem
elsart-num-names
elsart-num-sort
elsart-num
active2006
mslapa
ltugbib
apacitex
apacite
spiebib
abbrvurl
IEEEtranSN
IEEEtranSA
IEEEtranS
IEEEtran
IEEEtranN
phaip
chicago
phapalik
phpf
phjcp
newapa
humannat
phnflet
phreport
phnf
is-abbrv
phrmp
phiaea
phcpc
phppcf
jas99
econometrica
chicagoa
law
smfplain
smfalpha
gatech-thesis
agsm
kluwer
siam-letters
abbrv-letters
aiaa
acmtrans
plabbrv
savetrees
aunsnot
aabbrv
anotit
dk-abbrv
ier
econometrica-fr
ajae
ecta
econometrica
xagsm
texsis
ieeetr
abbrv
acm
siam
angew-mc
angew
rsc-mc
rsc
abbrvnat
gerapali
gerabbrv
agufull
agu`